# Faster swipe transition in flutter bottom navigation bar

Tags: animation, flutter, dart, transition, bottomnavigationview

Does anyone know how to make the swipe transition go faster? I am aware on the "on tab" transition: `controller.animateToPage(index,duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),curve: Curves.easeInOut);`  but i would like to know if there is any option for the onPageChanged.

Thanks!

Comment: Which swipe are you referring to?

Comment: @MiguelRuivo When you want to change screen you can swipe left or right and it changes. I refer to that swipe.